# Permission issue with samba 4 on Centos 7.4

Tags: linux, samba

I am seeing some weird permissions issues with samba 4 that I don't understand.

I have an XFS partition mounted on `/storage/test-xfs`, shared with a basic section:

```
# /storage/test-xfs is a mount of /dev/mapper/storage-text-xfs
[public]
path = /storage/test-xfs
comment = bla bla
```

When accessing this from `smbclient //localhost/public`, I get access denied message when doing a simple `ls`. Now, if I instead "export" a subdirectory of the filesystem, say `/storage/test-xfs/foo`:

```
[public]
path = /storage/test-xfs/foo
comment = bla bla
```

That works. I am not sure I understand why, but maybe sharing the "root" of a fs is not possible.

Now, for the really weird aspect. If I create another directory `/storage/test-xfs/bar` with `mkdir`, with the same owner/group and exactly same permissions, and export it with

```
[public-bar]
path = /storage/test-xfs/bar
comment = bla bla
```

I get permissions denied when doing ls in `smbclient //localhost/public-bar`. I thought maybe it was ACL, so I made sure that the output of `getfacl` for both `test-xfs/foo` and `test-xfs/bar` are exactly the same, but still the same error from smbclient. If instead of creating the directory `test-xfs/bar` with `mkdir`, I actually copy with `cp -a foo bar`, then I can do `ls` successfully. It is as if there is something besides Unix and ACL permissions that control access, but I cannot figure out what it is.

Any idea/pointer on what is going on ?

I am using samba 4.7.1 from Centos 7.4, the OS is up to date.